# SPFx Graph API Response Handling

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

My SPFx webpart is working well until I try to return the result of an Graph API call. The below code is trying to get the users that have permissions to the root file library for the site the webpart is installed.

The `console.log("Reached the Graph")` shows up in the inspector console so I'm guessing it has something to do with the `.push()` I'm using to append each returned record to the `response` declared at the beginning of the method.

I also tried the more documented `.forEach()` below without success. **Any Ideas?**

```
  private _loadUser(): MicrosoftGraph.Permission[] {
    let response: MicrosoftGraph.Permission[];
    this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient()
    .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
      let apiUrl: string = '/groups/'+this.props.group+'/drive/items/root/permissions';
      client
        .api(apiUrl)
        .version("v1.0")
        .get((error?, result?: MicrosoftGraph.Permission[], rawResponse?: any) => {
          // handle the response
          if(error){
            console.error(error);
          }
          if (result) {
            console.log("Reached the Graph");
            for (let res of result){
              response.push(res);
            }
          }
        }
      );
    });
    return response;
  }
```

```
            result.forEach(element => {
              response.push(element);
              console.log(element.grantedTo.user.displayName);
            });
```

Comment: please let me know if you got the answer. facing same issue,

Comment: Unfortunately the most I've found is that you have to use the Promise<Any> in js/ts, and I've shifted the project to be Blazor/C# to await HttpClient.PostAsync<User>().